# class property not initialize for xamarin form cross platform ony for IOS

Tags: class, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am using Xamarin Cross Platform application to build a sample login form. The following code is just taking the email and password value and giving result. The unique problem is when i run this for Android emulator everything is working fine. The class object LoginDTO hold the value of Username , password but when i run the code for IOS the username ,password is not holding the value and after explicit assign it showing null.

I don't know what is wrong here. I appreciate your help.

```
                LoginDTO objLogin = new LoginDTO();
                objLogin.UserName = email;
                objLogin.Password = password;
                UserManagerService umanager = new UserManagerService();
                blnresult = await umanager.ValidateLogin(objLogin);
```

Comment: Hi , could you share the code of `LoginDTO` ? This will be helpful to check where problem is .

Comment: public class LoginDTO : BaseDTO
    {

        private string _userName = string.Empty;

        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return _userName;
            }
            set
            {
                _userName = value;

            }
        }

        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public LoginDTO(string username, string password)
        {
            _userName = username;
            Password = password;

        }

Comment: Noting specific here it is working for Android but not for Ios

Comment: Have a check with `UserManagerService` whehter has data content in iOS .Maybe not getting api data in iOS .